# PHP search feature

Tags: php, jquery, sql, search-engine

Im working on a PHP/SQL project where one of the html pages contains a register of customers. In order to find a specific customer i've implemented a search feature based on two input forms (first name, last name).

When the user initially loads the page every customer can be found in a table. When the user then searches for a customer only the matched customers will be displayed. When the page is refreshed or loaded again via the menu I want it to display every customer again. This is where my problem lies. I've tried to find a solution but still havn't found a any. I know I have to use `unset($_SESSION['fname'])` etc but I do not know where. If a search has been made and the user refreshes the page the search result is still there, how can I fix this? I've tried the unset on several places but it always ends up preventing me from doing a search and instead displays every customer.

I've posted the code below:

```
<?php

//Display all
if(!isset($_SESSION['fname']) && !isset($_SESSION['lname']))
{
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY lname");

$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
}

//Perform a search
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  if(!isset($_SESSION['fname']) && !isset($_SESSION['lname']))
  {
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
    $_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];

    header('location:customers.php');
  }
}

//Display search result
if(isset($_SESSION['fname']) && isset($_SESSION['lname']))
{
  $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
  $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];

  //Enable binded param to be used in LIKE clause
  $fnameString = '%'.$fname.'%';
  $lnameString = '%'.$lname.'%';

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE fname LIKE :fname AND lname LIKE :lname");
  $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fnameString, PDO:: PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lnameString, PDO:: PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();
  $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
}

//Print
foreach ($res as $row)
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="customer.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fname." ".$row->lname; ?></a></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->street; ?><p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->zip; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->city; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->email; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->phone; ?></p></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reasons to use $_SESSION, I would just handle the search form as GET and check for params in the code.

```
<?php

//Display all
if(!$_GET['fname'] && !$_GET['lname'])
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY lname");

    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
}else{


  //Enable binded param to be used in LIKE clause
  $fnameString = '%'.$_GET['fname'].'%';
  $lnameString = '%'.$_GET['lname'].'%';

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE fname LIKE :fname AND lname LIKE :lname");
  $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fnameString, PDO:: PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lnameString, PDO:: PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();
  $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
}

//Print
foreach ($res as $row)
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="customer.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fname." ".$row->lname; ?></a></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->street; ?><p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->zip; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->city; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->email; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row->phone; ?></p></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

?>
```

if you do not wish to display the search string to the user, use POST.